# Missing R Console OS X 10.11.3, Homebrew user

Tags: r, terminal, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

Terminal says I have R version 3.2.3 "Wooden Christmas-Tree." I can run R directly in Terminal, but I want to use R Console as well. How do you install R Console in Terminal with Homebrew?

Comment: I'm confused as to the difference between "R" and "R Console." Since you want to run it in terminal, i'm assuming that you don't want a GUI.  What exactly are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: I think they're just saying they want to use essentially the mac version of RGui and they want to install it with homebrew?

Comment: Perhaps, R Studuo from https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ ? You will have IDE with the R console

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to continue to use Terminal and RStudio to run R scripts, and Sublime Text for writing scripts, until I need to do something that only the R GUI is capable of. Thanks for commenting.